# Flask não criando o banco de dados SQLite via SLQAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Boa-tarde a todos!

De forma alguma meu código está criando o banco de dados via SQL Alchemy, segue o trecho do código.

```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cliente'

    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    nome = db.Column(db.String)
    telefone = db.Column(db.String)
    cpf = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, nome, telefone, cpf, email):
        self.nome = nome
        self.telefone = telefone
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.email = email

db.create_all()
```

Já tentei até criando o banco de dados manualmente e apenas conectando-se a este, porém mesmo assim não funciona. Estou seguindo uma sequência de vídeos para aprender, porém, já está um pouco antiga, estou há algum tempo tentando solucionar isso e não consigo.

Meu sistema operacional é o Ubuntu, já tentei definir o caminho via realpath, também não funciona.

Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu solucionar?

Comment: Tenta usar `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` em vez de `SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI` e vê o que acontece. No caso a diferença é que está tudo maiúsculo.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!